# How to resolve "Could not import django.contrib.syndication.views.feed" error in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've updated my Django version to the latest nightly, and I'm getting the following error in the admin;

```
Could not import django.contrib.syndication.views.feed.  
View does not exist in module django.contrib.syndication.views.
```

I had this error in several views too because, indeed, `django.contrib.syndication.views.feed` was deprecated and has been removed.
I only had to add a

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
```

with

```
from django.contrib.syndication.feeds import Feed
```

Problem is that I can't find any references to `django.contrib.syndication.views.feed` anywhere, not even in the Django source, so I don't understand where the error is coming from and how to solve it.

The direct source of the error is

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in get_callable, line 100
```

but I can't find anything there either.

Hoping someone can help!

Comment: I have discovered that the source of the problem is - al least partially - in using {% comment_form_target %} in my template. There's probably some dynamic guessing going on as to where the form should point, importing feed along the way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[user643511](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643511/user643511) suggested that the error might be in my own code, not Django. However she didn't point out the real problem (which I understand since I didn't provide the right information). Only after days of digging I found that I had

```
url(r'^feeds/(?P<url>.*)/$', 'django.contrib.syndication.views.feed', {'feed_dict': feeds}),
```

in **urls.py**. And instead, I had to use

```
url(r'^feeds/(?P<url>.*)/$', 'django.contrib.syndication.views.Feed', {'feed_dict': feeds}),
```

Mind the capital F in views.Feed.

So if anyone passes by with similar trouble, check urls.py.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you have something wrong in your code, I make some test and the high-level feed-generating framework works fine. You only have to use the Feed class

```
django.contrib.syndication.views.Feed
```

This is a simple example: In your models

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from django.db import models

class Concept(models.Model):
    concept = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True, verbose_name=_('Concepto'))
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Descripcion'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % ( self.description or self.concept )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Concepto')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Conceptos')
        ordering = ['concept']

class LatestEntriesFeed(Feed):
    title = "My site news"
    link = "/sitenews/"
    description = "Updates on changes and additions."

    def items(self):
        return Concept.objects.all()

    def item_code(self, item):
        return item.code

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.description
```

and in your url:

```
from models import LatestEntriesFeed

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^latest/feed/$', LatestEntriesFeed()),    
)
```

result:

My site newshttp://example.com/sitenews/Updates on changes and additions.es-esTue, 12 Jul 2011 08:18:49 -0000

I hope that help.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but no that doesn't help at all. As I was saying, the problem I'm having is that I don't know where the error is occurring really, since I can't find any file on my entire system that imports feed from the wrong namespace. Looking at your source it is clear that you are not running a late version of Django, otherwise you're import would give problems to. from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed is deprecated.

Comment: I'm sorry, it turns out you were somewhat right after all; the error was in my own code. I had a reference to django.contrib.syndication.views.feed in my url, instead of django.contrib.syndication.views.Feed (God is in the details). I'll submit my own answer for those who pass by in the future.